# Unhandled Error when adding new Case

Tags: civicase

Using Joomla 3.8.6, CiviCRM 5.0.0, php 7.0.29, mysql 5.6.39

The following error has occurred since upgrading to 5.0.0.

When adding a new case, I enter the minimum field data and click Save, and the window hangs, with the rotating CiviCRM symbol gif. There is an entry in the CiviCRM log, but it is so huge that I have not been able to make any sense of it. The log entry is about 3Mb big.

There is also an error in the Apache log:
File does not exist: .../media/fef/js/tabs.min.map

And this is what I'm seeing in the browser console:

POST https://...../administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/case/add&action=add&context=case&cid=30&snippet=json
500 (Internal Server Error)
send    @   jquery.js?r=2i4CQ:10254
ajax    @   jquery.js?r=2i4CQ:9738
fileUploadXhr   @   jquery.form.js?r=2i4CQ:346
$.fn.ajaxSubmit @   jquery.form.js?r=2i4CQ:254
doAjaxSubmit    @   jquery.form.js?r=2i4CQ:890
dispatch    @   jquery.js?r=2i4CQ:5226
elemData.handle @   jquery.js?r=2i4CQ:4878
click   @   crm.ajax.js?r=2i4CQ:466
(anonymous) @   jquery-ui.js?r=2i4CQ:12443
dispatch    @   jquery.js?r=2i4CQ:5226
elemData.handle @   jquery.js?r=2i4CQ:4878

Comment: Jem - you could try this extension as it will give you a better view of your logs. https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer

Comment: Thanks! That's so much easier. I was able to quickly isolate the problem to an out-of-date extension.

Comment: cool - i added as an Answer to make it a more prominent suggestion for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer to the problem but definitely helps with accessing the log errors to help further diagnosis.

The excellent [Log Viewer](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer) extension gives UI access to your logs.